# C#: string[] to delimited string. Is there a one-liner?

Tags: c#, string, csv, arrays

What I'd prefer is something like:

```
string[] strArray = {"Hi", "how", "are", "you"};
string strNew = strArray.Delimit(chDelimiter);
```

However, there is no such function.  I've looked over MSDN and nothing looked to me as a function that would perform the same action.  I looked at StringBuilder, and again, nothing stood out to me. Does anyone know of a not to extremely complicated one liner to make an array a delimited string.  Thanks for your guys' help.

UPDATE:  Wow, lol, my bad.  I kept looking at the .Join on the array itself and it was bugging the hell out of me.  I didn't even look at String.Join.  Thanks guys.  Once it allows me to accept I shall.  Preciate the help.

Comment: Something like `String.Join(chDelimiter, array);` You might have to turn char into a string first. There is also a generic version. I suspect that LINQ can do this in an elegant way as well.

Comment: Yeah, I kept looking at the wrong join.  Thanks.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

For arrays, you can use:

```
string.Join(", ", strArray);
```

Personally, I use an extension method that I can apply to enumerable collections of all types:

```
public static string Flatten(this IEnumerable elems, string separator)
{
    if (elems == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (object elem in elems)
    {
        if (sb.Length > 0)
        {
            sb.Append(separator);
        }

        sb.Append(elem);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

...Which I use like so:

```
strArray.Flatten(", ");
```

Comment: Nice function.  My main purpose is we have a delimited file, put it into a program for editing with SQL Lite as the storing method, and then they want to sent it back out to a delimited file.  Once it lets me accept I shall.  Thanks.

Comment: In NET4.0, there is a `string.Join` overload you can use with any `IEnumerable` collection, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx

Comment: @Danko: Nice! As I move my applications to .NET 4, I will definitely favor the method you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: this approach also allows you to append a line separator also, with an extra parameter; the .Join approach requires an extra concat for the eol "\n"

Comment: ***Performance*** about `string.Join` _vs_ `strArray.Flatten` ?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the static [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) method:

`String strNew = String.Join(chDelimiter, strArray);`

---

**EDIT: In response to comment**:
Based on your comment, you can take several arrays, concatenate them together, and then join the entire resulting array.  You can do this by using the IEnumerable extension method `Concat`.  Here's an example:

```
//define my two arrays...
string[] strArray = { "Hi", "how", "are", "you" };
string[] strArray2 = { "Hola", "como", "esta", "usted" };

//Concatenate the two arrays together (forming a third array) and then call join on it...
string strNew = String.Join(",", strArray.Concat(strArray2));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What bothers me is that if something is a string[], then when I do .Join, I should still have that option available.  I should have the option to join arrays and the option to JOIN that array.  :)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that.  I didn't necessarily mean that I need it, I'm saying that when you have a string[] and you follow the variable with .Join (strArray.Join(  ), you don't get the Join(string delimiter, string[] strArray) option, you get some other join options.  I think the string[] should also have the .Join(string delimiter, string[] strArray) option, but it would be .Join(string delimiter) since it already is an array.  Did I make that clear because I confused myself.  :)

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [String.Join()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk0xe5h0.aspx).

Your sample must look like this :

```
        string delimiter = ","
        string[] strArray = { "Hi", "how", "are", "you" };
        string strNew = String.Join(delimiter, strArray);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx)

```
string[] strArray = {"Hi", "how", "are", "you"};
string strNew = String.Join("," strArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

in this case, String.Join() is probably the easiest way to go, you can equally use LINQ though

```
var comSeparatedStrings = strings.Aggregate((acc, item) => acc + ", " + item);
```

Comment: Aggregate is much slower though, due to not using a StringBuilder behind the scenes (iirc).