# C# Dynamic IF Else Statment

Tags: c#, if-statement

```
allrowcol[i] = rowcol + "||";
```

Is it possible to put :

```
if (loop == allrowcol.ToString())
```

If not, how can I place a few values inside an `if` statement?

I need to have a few values in the `if`, and this value is generated from a text file.

e.g. `if(loop==11||14||15||16")`

My array for the `allrowcol.ToString()` is "11||14||15||16||". `rowcol` is the number that I extract from my text file. But my `if` (read as a whole string).

What can I do?

Comment: what is `loop`?what is `allrowcol`?what are you trying to do?.am not able to understand ur problem! Edit ur question before it gets closed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess you are asking how to test multiple items in a collection of unknown size. If so:

```
bool isMatch = true;
string valueToCompare = "some value";

for( int i = 0; i < allrowcol.Length; i++ ){
   if( allrowcol[i] != valueToCompare ){
       isMatch = false;
       break;
   }
}

if( isMatch ){
    // do something
}
```

Alternatively, if you just want to test all values at once, then concatenate them, e.g. using `string.Join()`. See this question: [C#: string[] to delimited string. Is there a one-liner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558246/c-string-to-delimited-string-is-there-a-one-liner)

Comment: Yes you answered my question. Thanks!

Comment: @TanLiangLiang if that solves your problem..u should accept the ans..

Comment: Sorry i'm new to this, where to accept?